# Lead Conversion Screen looks different in Enterprise edition

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, leads, lead-conversion

For one of my salesforce instance, I'm seeing this lead conversion page, which doesn't look good.[image].

This is in enterprise edition. First time I'm seeing this type of lead conversion page and it is standard page.

Below is the lead conversion page in classic:
[image]

Where as in my developer environment or any other environment, I have seen below screen:
[image]

Any Idea what may be issue or how to resolve this?

Comment: are you sure the lead convert button wasn't overridden in the first org with a VF page?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I have added the classic lead conversion view, where it looks fine?

Comment: what does the Lead Lightning page look like?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by enabling **Use Apex Lead Convert**.

To enable this setting we need to raise a case with Salesforce and once it's enabled, it resolved the issue.